How can I insert null in column NULL for the type TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE
I have table with column 'additional_session_end_ts' which has type TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE  and in this column there can be null values.
I have simple method in repository in my Java application:
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO auction_proposal_list_link (auction_proposal_id, auction_list_id, mini_session_start_time, " +
               "mini_session_end_time, additional_session_end_ts, mini_session_start_time_fixed, mini_session_number) " +
               "VALUES (:auctionProposalId, :auctionListId, :sessionStartTime, :sessionEndTime, " +
               "CASE WHEN :additionalSessionEndTime IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(:additionalSessionEndTime AS time) ELSE CAST(NULL AS time) END, " +
               ":startTimeFixed, :miniSessionNumber)", 
       nativeQuery = true)
void insertAuctionBySeries(
    @Param("auctionProposalId") Long auctionProposalId,
    @Param("auctionListId") Long auctionListId,
    @Param("sessionStartTime") LocalTime sessionStartTime,
    @Param("sessionEndTime") LocalTime sessionEndTime,
    @Param("additionalSessionEndTime") LocalTime additionalSessionEndTime,
    @Param("startTimeFixed") Boolean startTimeFixed,
    @Param("miniSessionNumber") Long miniSessionNumber
);

and I always see an error:

InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statementcaused by: SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement caused by: PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to time without time zone

And this error happened because I've tried to insert in additional_session_end_ts NULL.
I've tried different approaches like above, COALESCE(CAST(:additionalSessionEndTime AS time), NULL::time), just insert null and nothing works for me.
I just want to have the simple logic - insert some value in additional_session_end_ts column or insert NULL if value is null.
How can I do it?


Why are you doing the CASTs?  2) Look at the Postgres log to see what is hitting the database.


By the way, TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE is the wrong data type to use when recoding a moment, a specific point on the timeline. For that use the type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE in Postgres (and standard SOL), and use java.time.OffsetDateTime class in Java.

You might have more success when posting here if your contrive a simple example, cut back to the bare minimum needed to show your issue. And a complete examples, such as showing the SQL creating the table. See: [MCVE].

Your INSERT command works ok when values supplied are compatible.
The error you are geting implicates that you are trying to cast BYTEA datatype (byte array) as TIME datatype. Check the values passed to INSERT command.
INSERT INTO auction_proposal_list_link 
  (auction_proposal_id, 
   auction_list_id, 
   mini_session_start_time,
   mini_session_end_time, 
   additional_session_end_ts, 
   mini_session_start_time_fixed, 
   mini_session_number
  ) 
VALUES (1, 
        1, 
        CAST('01:00:00' as TIME), 
        CAST('02:00:00' as TIME), 
        CASE WHEN 1=2 
             THEN CAST('03:00:00' AS TIME) 
        ELSE CAST(NULL AS TIME) 
        END, 
        CAST('01:00:00' as TIME),
        100
       )

Select * From auction_proposal_list_link




auction_proposal_id
auction_list_id
mini_session_start_time
mini_session_end_time
additional_session_end_ts
mini_session_start_time_fixed
mini_session_number




1
1
01:00:00
02:00:00
null
01:00:00
100



fiddle
